# using MultiMatchQueryBuilder for 'and' keyword query search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a bunch of documents stored in elasticsearch with fields `title` and `abstract`. I have to search documents for queries like `'word1 word2 ..'`. Currently I am using spring data

```
MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder = new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(query, "abstract", "title");
Iterable<Document> result = documentRepository.search(multiMatchQueryBuilder);
```

This gives me all the documents that contain `word1` or `word2`. How can I match all the keywords? It should give me documents that have all the words in the query `word1` and `word2`. Basically I want an `and` and not `or` of all the keywords in the search query.

Comment: DO you want the order to be same too (phrase_search)? i.e If you search for ''word1 word2', you don't want  ''word2 word1' to be retrieved.

Comment: Have you tried `new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(query, "abstract", "title").operator(Operator.AND)`?

Comment: @Val, that seems to work. I should have played around with the builder a bit more.

Comment: @Richa no ordering doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `AND` operator like this:

```
MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder = new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(query, "abstract", "title")
   .operator(Operator.AND);     // <---- add this
Iterable<Document> result = documentRepository.search(multiMatchQueryBuilder);
```

Comment: Could you please check whether my request is possible please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63007991/elastic-search-tokenization-and-multi-match-query